# jQuery page-flip animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a pageflip script called Moleskine Notebook. Inside the jquery.booklet.1.1.0.js file there is a function called next which turns the page. I want to call this function from my html file.

I tried "$mybook.next();" but it didn't work, I think I have to do something with jQuery.data() as it states on jquery.booklet.1.1.0.js file (lines 100-103)

```
//store data for api calls
b.data('booklet',true);
b.data('id', id);
b.data('total', src.children().length);
```

Here is the script:
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/MoleskineNotebook/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [the API docs](http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/options):

```
$('#mybook').booklet('next');
```